# Would a brick TV stand withstand the weight of a TV?

Tags: brick

The TV is 64 " and probably weighs 60+ lbs.  I would like to create a TV stand in order to place the TV off the floor likely just 2' high.  The width and deph would be the same as the base of the TV.
Would be bricks withstand the weight of the TV?

Comment: Cinderblock, or regular brick. 60 Lbs should not be a problem.

Comment: Supporting the weight isn't an issue, but if you really intend to make it the same size as the TV base, the structural stability may be. My TV's base is about 18" wide and 6" deep -  if I built a brick platform with those same dimensions, there's not much stability front to back, it could easily tip over (or be pulled over by a child). So make sure you secure the TV to the wall.

Comment: Voting to close. OP hasn't been back to answer questions and it's collecting chatty comments. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Bricks will easily withstand the weight of the TV. What you may need to worry about is the floor withstanding the weight of 2 feet of bricks under the TV. Since you don't mention the size of the base, it's difficult to know exactly how much weight we are talking about, but a 2 foot stack of bricks is a considerable load. Brick weighs roughly 120 lbs per cubic foot, so a stack 5 feet by 1 foot by 2 feet would weigh 1,200 lbs and exert a floor loading of 240 lbs/square foot (plus the 60 lbs for the TV divided by the area of the base - another 12 lbs/square foot if the base is 5 feet x 1 foot, so 252 lbs / sq ft.)

Residential floors are usually deigned for loadings more like 40 lbs/sq ft, so that's a pretty severe load. While it's similar to 5 large guys all standing in a line, the 5 large guys don't stand in one place all the time, nor usually quite that close to each other. If your floors are concrete slabs, this may not apply to you.

A much lighter support will easily hold up a 60 lb TV, and can be made of wood, or milk crates, or even rigid foam plastic. A 2ft high bookcase or "sofa table" would probably work fine.

Comment: Love this answer. Reminded me a little (stream of consciousness) of a consulting gig once where the client had run thousands of "what-if" scenarios to derive a magic multiplier which was something like 0.28. Except that as I was evaluating the problem, the multiplier was clearly an algebraic variable with a non-constant value in the general neighborhood of 0.28 most of the time. At the next presentation the client looked at the equations and asked "where's my multiplier?" I started explaining the main equation, and the client said "No, don't bring math into this!"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the feat like that was accomplished, well with the help of a few planks to reduce the weight.

A simple but daring pine and brick shelf from [Crazy Craft Lady](https://thecrazycraftlady.com/diy-concrete-block-bookshelf/)  support a smaller media device but might be able to hold a small TV, and even bigger TV with more bricks and wider shelves.  Personally I would just put a couple of bricks or cinder blocks under the TV legs, rather than building the great pyramid.  The top upper level of the design on this photo. Well, maybe two levels max.[image: Crazy Craft Lady's Bookshelf]

Lower but wider build, with an additional column, as on [Ellen Bradley-Cheung's pin](https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/78461218484614101/)  below could hold a pretty heavy television
[image: brick tv stand]

Frankly, for heavy TVs the cinders blocks are way more common choice. There are several cinder stand examples over internet, but the below massive cinder block stand occurs most often (especially on Latin, Russian and [Arabic](https://www.nobaraneh.com/8906/%D8%AA%D8%B2%DB%8C%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D9%88-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AE%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84) sites)

[image: https://www.nobaraneh.com/8906/%D8%AA%D8%B2%DB%8C%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D9%88-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AE%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84]

I think 60 pounds is very light weight and brick will do just fine even if you meant plastic yoga bricks.

At the moment in my place a piece of wood and a pile of thick old electronics serves as a TV raiser. From a distance it looks like proper tv furniture. When moving TV the wood piece felt after which I glued wood to electronics with two-side adhesive tape. I noted sometimes free standing bricks columns are a bit unstable but you might need something stronger than usual adhesive tape to fix them.

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand this; would you clarify? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: It's likely that "a couple of bricks" isn't going to get the 2 foot height the OP was looking for.

Comment: Interesting setup, and pretty cool looking - is this yours? Are you the OP under a new account? I'm going to go out on a limb and say those boards aren't going to last for more than a year or two before they start sagging. All the weight above is concentrated as a point load directly in the middle of the spans below and that's not particularly good for what is probably particle board with melamine on it. Of course, if that's 1/4" steel, then that's a whole different story...

Comment: No. As I mentioned I would keep it up to two level, something more like https://img.culturacolectiva.com/content/2016/03/librero-decorar-con-ladrillos.jpg or https://www.pinterest.com.mx/pin/391813236335783986/ . I cannot exclude that it is built by OP

Comment: I'm confused here. Are you simply finding random images on the web and posting them as examples of this being done or are these pics of things you've done yourself? If these are images from the web, please post the image source(s) according to SE policy. Also, bear in mind that this is a 5 year old question and the OP has probably moved on to a different TV & stand by now...

Comment: ok, sources are added. Will bear

Comment: These are some really dumb (and dumb looking) DIY examples.   The first one is about to fall over.

Comment: with some adhesive it will not

Comment: but feel free to post your smart (or smart looking) examples